# symantec backupexec 11d slow backup

Tags: backup, backupexec, symantec

I have a IBM blade center H with modules HS21 type 8853 with Windows 2003R2 (32 bits). My backup is very slow (transfer starts with 16MB/min and slow down o 3 MB/min). I have update all firmware, all driver, nothing help. Any sugestions what can be wrong? Size of a backuped data no matter. It can be 100MB or 10GB, effect always is the same

Comment: What kind of tape drive and SCSI interface are you using?

Comment: tape drive is Overland ARCvault and SCSI interface is a Adaptec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in LTO driver. I changed driver from symantec to Microsoft native and speed increase to max.

Answer (score 0):

This might not apply to 11d, but in the past, I've noticed slower than usual backup speeds when not using the remote agents.

Comment: I'm using remote agents on all servers. But I notice interesting thing. When I use disk no LTO to store backup speed is OK. My LTO is Overland ARCvault 24

Answer (score 0):

Most speed issues I have seen have to do with the SCSI settings for the tape drive.  You will want to determine the SCSI ID of the tape drive (not the library) and enter the SCSI BIOS.  In the BIOS, enable "Disconnection", disable "Sync Negotiation", and then set the transfer rate to the maximum for your device (maybe 160MB/s).  Also, make sure your SCSI chain is correctly terminated.

Comment: I set "enable disconetion" to 'NO'(default was 'YES' and max speed 320) but I don't have "sync negotiation" option. Max speed sets automaticly to 160MB. Still not good